# Engine won't rev past 2500 in Park/Neutral

Tags: engine, ford, expedition

I am just through replacing the catalytic converters on an 06 Ford Expedition with about 151k miles on it. [To break in new cats](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27127/4152), you must run it at idle for about 5 minutes, then increase the engine speed to 2500 for two minutes.

I broke the cats in just fine, then let everything cool down for about 15 minutes. I took it out for a drive of about 5 minutes. Everything seems fine. When I got it back to the house, I parked the truck and while sitting, tried to rev the engine up, but it would only go to 2500 rpm (well maybe just a little over it). It acted like there was a engine rev limiter keeping it at this speed (bounced a little above/below) for about 10 seconds, the settled out to an even 2500 rpm *even with the pedal planted on the floor*. I thought there might be an issue with it, so I took it out for a drive again. I nailed the accelerator and it hopped right up past 4500 rpm without an issue.

The question is: ***Is this normal behavior for Ford vehicles with drive by wire?*** Or maybe just for Expeditions? If it is, has Ford given a reason for programming their vehicles this way? Personally, if I want to rev my engine to the moon, I want the system to allow me to do it. Only allowing the engine to rev to 2500 makes me think there are other issues with the vehicle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is normal behavior.

I've test-driven a 2010 Ford Explorer; when the car is in P it will not allow you to go past 2500 rpm. When in D, no such limit.

Comment: Agreed GM does the same thing with ETC motors.